# How to count observations per ID in R? (and obtain mean and standard deviation)

Tags: r, count, mean

I have a dataset where participants have recorded a different number of observed data points for a key variable (e.g. some where measured 5 days, others 7). I would like to get an count of how many days participants were measured, as well as a standard deviation on that. I tried using the count function but it did not work out for me.

My data looks like this:

```
*Participant_Id    OBSvalue
001             8574
001             9757
001             8487
002             11202
002             13949
003             10203
004             8963*
```

I would like to get something like:

```
*Mean number of observation for participants: 2.4
Standard deviation: 0.5*
```

Thank you in advance!

Best

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create a data frame / tibble
data <- tribble(
          ~Participant_Id, ~OBSvalue,
          "001",             8574,
          "001",            9757,
          "001",             8487,
          "002",             11202,
          "002",             13949,
          "003",             10203,
          "004",             8963
        )

# Caluclate summary statistics by participant
summary <- data %>% 
             group_by(Participant_Id) %>% 
             summarise(
               N=n(),
               Mean=mean(OBSvalue),
               SD=sd(OBSvalue),
               .groups="drop"
             )
summary

# Calculate mean number of values per participant
summary %>% summarise(MeanN=mean(N), .groups="drop")
```

Giving

```
  Participant_Id     N   Mean    SD
  <chr>          <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 001                3  8939.  709.
2 002                2 12576. 1942.
3 003                1 10203    NA 
4 004                1  8963    NA
```

and

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  MeanN
  <dbl>
1  1.75
```

[This site](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) is an excellent start to learning basic data science in R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table` and then `mean` and `sd`.

```
mean(table(x[1]))
#[1] 1.75
> sd(table(x[1]))
#[1] 0.9574271
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Participant_Id    OBSvalue
001             8574
001             9757
001             8487
002             11202
002             13949
003             10203
004             8963")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require(data.table)
x <- data.table(
  Participant_Id = c("001",  "001",  "001",  "002",  "002",  "003",  "004"),
  OBSvalue = c(8574, 9757, 8487, 11202, 13949, 10203, 8963)
)
# mean of count of Participant_Id
x[, .N, by = Participant_Id][, mean(N)]
# sd of count of Participant_Id
x[, .N, by = Participant_Id][, sd(N)]
```